# Plotting Heatmap with different column/line widths

Tags: gnuplot

I am simulating something and want to figure out the influence of two parameters. Therefore I vary them both and look for the result on each pair of parameter values and get a result like:

```
  0  1000  2000  3000  4000  5000  ....
0  13.2  14.8  19.9  25.5  27.3 ...
1000  21.3  25.9  32.3 etc.
2000  etc.
3000
4000
....
```

To visualize them, I use gnuplot, creating a heatmap, which works perfectly fine, showing me colors and height:

```
reset 

set terminal qt

set title "Test"
unset key
set tic scale 0

set palette rgbformula 7,5,15
set cbrange [0:100]
set cblabel "Transmission"

set pm3d at s interpolate 1,1

unset surf

set xlabel "U_{Lense} [V]"
set ylabel "E_{Start} [eV]"

set datafile separator "\t"
splot "UT500test.csv" matrix rowheaders columnheaders
```

Now I want to look more detailed on some areas on my heatmap, and vary my parameters in steps of 100 difference, not 1000 as shown in the table above. But because the simulation takes quite a long time, I just do this for some areas, so my table looks like this:

```
0  1000  2000  2100  2200  2300  2400 ...  2900  3000  4000  ...
...
```

Now I want to show this in the heatmap, too. But everytime I tried this, all the bins on the heatmap, no matter if 1000 or 100 difference are of the same width. But I want the ones with 100 difference to be only 1/10 of the width of the 1000 differences. Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something with plotting style `with boxxyerror`. It's pretty straightforward, except the way to get the x-coordinates into an array which will be used later during plotting. Maybe, there are smarter solutions.

**Script:**

```
### heatmap with irregular spacing
reset session
unset key 

$Data <<EOD
0.00    0.00    1000    2000    2100    2200    2300    2400    3000    4000
1000    0.75    0.75    0.43    0.34    0.61    0.74    0.66    0.97    0.58
1100    0.82    0.90    0.18    0.12    0.87    0.15    0.01    0.57    0.97
1200    0.10    0.15    0.68    0.73    0.55    0.07    0.98    0.89    0.01
1300    0.67    0.38    0.41    0.85    0.37    0.45    0.49    0.21    0.98
1400    0.76    0.53    0.68    0.09    0.22    0.40    0.59    0.33    0.08
2000    0.37    0.32    0.30    NaN     0.33    NaN     0.73    0.94    0.96
3000    0.07    0.61    0.37    0.54    0.32    0.28    0.62    0.51    0.48
4000    0.79    0.98    0.78    0.06    0.16    0.45    0.83    0.50    0.10
5000    0.49    0.95    0.29    0.59    0.55    0.88    0.29    0.47    0.93
EOD

stats $Data nooutput
BoxHalfWidth=50
# put first row into array
array ArrayX[STATS_columns]
set table $Dummy
    plot for [i=1:STATS_columns] $Data u (ArrayX[i]=column(i)) every ::0::0 with table
unset table

plot for [i=2:STATS_columns] $Data u (ArrayX[i]):1:(BoxHalfWidth):(BoxHalfWidth):i every ::1 with boxxyerror fs solid 1.0 palette
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Edit:**

With a little bit more effort you can as well generate a plot which covers the whole area.
In contrast to the simpler code from @Ethan, the recangles are centered on the datapoint coordinates and have the color of the actual datapoint z-value. Furthermore, the datapoint `(2200,2000)` is also plotted. The borders of the rectangles are halfway between matrix points. The outer rectangles have dimensions equal to the x and y distance to the next inner matrix point.

***Revision:*** (simplified version, works for gnuplot>=5.0.1)

The following solution works for gnuplot 5.0.1, but not for 5.0.0 (haven't found out yet why).

There will be a warning:  `warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values` which can be ignored.
I noticed that there seems to be a [bug(?!)](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2539/) with the matrix column index, but you can fix it with:

```
colIdxFix(n) = (r0=r1,r1=column(-1),r0==r1?c=c+1:c=1)   # fix for missing column index in a matrix

plot r1=c=0 $Data nonuniform matrix u 1:2:(colIdxFix(0)) ....
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.1)

```
### heatmap with irregular spacing with filled area
# compatible with gnuplot>=5.0.1
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.00    0.00    1000    2000    2100    2200    2300    2400    3000    4000
1000    0.75    0.75    0.43    0.34    0.61    0.74    0.66    0.97    0.58
1100    0.82    0.90    0.18    0.12    0.87    0.15    0.01    0.57    0.97
1200    0.10    0.15    0.68    0.73    0.55    0.07    0.98    0.89    0.01
1300    0.67    0.38    0.41    0.85    0.37    0.45    0.49    0.21    0.98
1400    0.76    0.53    0.68    0.09    0.22    0.40    0.59    0.33    0.08
2000    0.37    0.32    0.30    NaN     0.33    NaN     0.73    0.94    0.96
3000    0.07    0.61    0.37    0.54    0.32    0.28    0.62    0.51    0.48
4000    0.79    0.98    0.78    0.06    0.16    0.45    0.83    0.50    0.10
5000    0.49    0.95    0.29    0.59    0.55    0.88    0.29    0.47    0.93
EOD

# get irregular x- and y-values into string
Xs = Ys = ""
stats $Data matrix u ($1==0 ? Ys=Ys.sprintf(" %g",$3) : 0, \
                      $2==0 ? Xs=Xs.sprintf(" %g",$3) : 0) nooutput

# box extension d in dn (negative) and dp (positive) direction
d(vs,n0,n1) = abs(real(word(vs,n0+1))-real(word(vs,n1+1)))/2.
dn(vs,n)    = (n==1                  ? (n0=1,n1=2)     : (n0=n,n1=n-1), -d(vs,n0,n1))
dp(vs,n)    = (Ns=words(vs)-1, n>=Ns ? (n0=Ns-1,n1=Ns) : (n0=n,n1=n+1),  d(vs,n0,n1))

unset key 
set offset 1,1,1,1
set style fill solid 1.0

colIdxFix(n) = (r0=r1,r1=column(-1),r0==r1?c=c+1:c=1)   # fix for missing column index in a matrix (bug?!)

plot r1=c=0 $Data nonuniform matrix u 1:2:($1+dn(Xs,colIdxFix(0))):($1+dp(Xs,c)): \
                    ($2+dn(Ys,int(column(-1))+1)):($2+dp(Ys,int(column(-1))+1)):3 w boxxy palette
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Edit2:** (I leave this here for gnuplot 5.0.0)

Just for fun, here is the "retro-version" for gnuplot 5.0:

gnuplot5.0 does not support arrays. Although, gnuplot5.0 supports datablocks, but apparently indexing like `$Datablock[1]` does not work. So, the workaround-around is to put the matrix X,Y coordinates into strings `CoordsX` and `CoordsY` and get the coordinates with `word()`. If there is not another limitation with string and `word()`, the following worked with gnuplot5.0 and gave the same result as above.

**Script:**

```
### heatmap with irregular spacing with filled area
# compatible with gnuplot 5.0
reset session
unset key 

$Data <<EOD
0.00    0.00    1000    2000    2100    2200    2300    2400    3000    4000
1000    0.75    0.75    0.43    0.34    0.61    0.74    0.66    0.97    0.58
1100    0.82    0.90    0.18    0.12    0.87    0.15    0.01    0.57    0.97
1200    0.10    0.15    0.68    0.73    0.55    0.07    0.98    0.89    0.01
1300    0.67    0.38    0.41    0.85    0.37    0.45    0.49    0.21    0.98
1400    0.76    0.53    0.68    0.09    0.22    0.40    0.59    0.33    0.08
2000    0.37    0.32    0.30    NaN     0.33    NaN     0.73    0.94    0.96
3000    0.07    0.61    0.37    0.54    0.32    0.28    0.62    0.51    0.48
4000    0.79    0.98    0.78    0.06    0.16    0.45    0.83    0.50    0.10
5000    0.49    0.95    0.29    0.59    0.55    0.88    0.29    0.47    0.93
EOD

stats $Data nooutput
ColCount = int(STATS_columns-1)
RowCount = int(STATS_records-1)
# put first row and column into arrays

CoordsX = ""
set table $Dummy
    set xrange[0:1]     # to avoid warnings
    do for [i=2:ColCount+1] {
        plot $Data u (Value=column(i)) every ::0::0 with table
        CoordsX = CoordsX.sprintf("%g",Value)." "
    }
unset table
CoordsY = ""
set table $Dummy
    do for [i=1:RowCount] {
        plot $Data u (Value=$1) every ::i::i with table
        CoordsY= CoordsY.sprintf("%g",Value)." "
    }
unset table

dx(i) = (word(CoordsX,i)-word(CoordsX,i-1))*0.5
dy(i) = (word(CoordsY,i)-word(CoordsY,i-1))*0.5
ndx(i,j) = word(CoordsX,i) - (i-1<1        ? dx(i+1) : dx(i))
pdx(i,j) = word(CoordsX,i) + (i+1>ColCount ? dx(i)   : dx(i+1))
ndy(i,j) = word(CoordsY,j) - (j-1<1        ? dy(j+1) : dy(j))
pdy(i,j) = word(CoordsY,j) + (j+1>RowCount ? dy(j)   : dy(j+1))

set xrange[ndx(1,1):pdx(ColCount,1)]
set yrange[ndy(1,1):pdy(1,RowCount)]
set tic out
plot for [i=2:ColCount+1] $Data u (real(word(CoordsX,i-1))):1:(ndx(i-1,int($0))):(pdx(i-1,int($0))): \
    (ndy(i-1,int($0+1))):(pdy(i-1,int($0+1))):i every ::1 with boxxyerror fs solid 1.0 palette
### end of script
```

Comment: that is actually very impressive, it just don't works for me..
when I try to run the exact code you put above, it gives me an error:

    array ArrX[ColCount]
    ^
    "heat.g", line 51: invalid command

do you have any Idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: I just looked it up and it seems, the array data type is available in Gnuplot 5.2, but my version is 5.0

Comment: is there any reason why you can't update to 5.2.6? There might be a workaround for 5.0 to mimic arrays but the code will get a bit longer.

Comment: On my workplace I have no access to the software version so I have to use version 5.0. I tried the version for 5.2.6 on my personal computer and also your workaround for version 5.0 on my worklpace. Both worked perfectly fine and did exactly what I tried to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The extra steps with `stats` are not necessary. 
You can access the true coordinates directly as a nonuniform matrix:

```
  set offset 100,100,100,100
  plot $Data matrix nonuniform using 1:2:3 with points pt 5 lc palette
```

[image]

The missing piece is to fill in the full area rather than plotting single points. You can do this using pm3d:

```
  set pm3d corners2color mean
  set view map
  splot $Data matrix nonuniform with pm3d
```

[image]
The colors do not match the previous plot because pm3d considers all 4 corners of each box when assigning a color.  I told it to take the mean value (that's the default) but many other variants are possible. You could smooth the coloring further with `set pm3d interpolate 3,3`

Comment: good and short solution for covering the whole area. However, I am missing the data point `(2200,2000)`. Will it also work if it is not a strict matrix, i.e. not a constant number of columns over the rows?

Comment: That's exactly what I try to do. With this solution the color rectangle are not centered at my parameter-pairs e.g. 1000 and 2000 but at the center, so at 1500 and 2500 or so, which I first thought would be a problem.

But If I understand the usage of corners2color right, it actually improves my visualization by lower statistic errors, so I'm fine with this, thank you!