# Gnuplot nonuniform matrix with labels and image gives different plots

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

I am trying to plot the nonuniform matrix for the following data:

```html
,1,2,4,5,7
6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0
8, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1
3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3
1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3
```

When tried with labels

```html
set datafile separator ","
plot 'num2.dat' nonuniform matrix using  with labels
```

I get the labels in all the desired x and y coordinates according to my data as in picture "[image: matrix-nonuniform-label.jpg]

When I try to make the heatmap with the following code:

```html
set datafile separator ","
set palette defined (1 "red",2 "blue",3 "green",4 "black",5 "violet")
plot 'num2.dat' nonuniform matrix with image
```

the x and y coordinates are not scattered as in label plot.  For example (7,9) coordinate has to have value 3.  It is not getting shown at all.  Can someone please help point out what is the missing thing here.[image: matrix-nonuniform-image.jpg]

Thanks in advance.
uv.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want the image plot to look like. What does it even mean to have an image in which only some pixels have a value?  If the idea is that you want a plot similar to the one you show with labels except that instead of a character "1" at position [x,y] you have a colored square, then try this:

```html
set datafile separator ","
set xrange [0:10]; set yrange [0:10]
plot 'num2.dat' nonuniform matrix using 1:2:3 with points pt 5 lc palette
```

[image]

You can adjust the size of the squares by adding a line

```
  set pointsize 3.   # multiplier for point size
```

Comment: Ethan, please have a look at matrix-nonuniform-image.jpg attached.  Please suggest some solution based on that.

Comment: I still don't understand what it is you are expecting instead of that, if not the non-connected pixels as I showed before. Can you make a rough sketch of what you want the plot to look like?

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** After revisiting this post, I noticed that I misunderstood your question and data. Ethan's answer is doing what you asked for, so what's wrong with it?

Here is a variation with plotting style `boxxyerror` (check `help boxxyerror`). With this you can give the width and height of the boxes in graph coordinates.
If you want the boxes to be expanded to close the gaps you could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039394/7295599).

**Script:**

```
### heatmap of nonuniform matrix with boxxyerrorbar
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 , 1, 2, 4, 5, 7
6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0
8, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1
3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3
1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3
EOD

set datafile separator comma
set size ratio -1
set palette defined (1 "red", 2 "blue", 3 "green", 4 "black", 5 "violet")
set style fill solid 1.0
set key noautotitle
set style textbox opaque

plot $Data nonuniform matrix u 1:2:(0.5):(0.5):3 w boxxy lc palette, \
        '' nonuniform matrix u 1:2:(sprintf("%g",$3)) w labels boxed
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]