# Gnuplot pm3d: 'NaN value' removes all surrounding rectangles

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I would like to plot a pm3d map, where data points are not equidistant on the axis.
Since the spacings for the x and y axis are identical, it is symmetrical, though.

The problem is whenever a value is "NaN", all of the four surrounding rectangles
are not plotted. In the data file below, this happens, for example, at (x,y)=(0.14,0.33) [image].

If the value is not 'NaN', then the four rectangles reappear.
I discovered this problem, when I tried to plot only the values >0 or <0, where the same happens.

I tried to search the documentation and the internet, but couldn't find anything on this.
Are there any solutions to this?

Plotscript:

```
set view map
set pm3d at b
set style data pm3d
set pm3d corners2color c1
set size ratio 1
set autoscale fix
set cbrange [-25:25]
set palette defined (-25 "blue", 0 "white", 25 "red")
set term png
set output "test.png"
splot "data.txt" u 1:2:3 notitle
set output
```

Data file:

```
0.0 0.0 1
0.0 0.08 -2
0.0 0.14 3
0.0 0.33 -4
0.0 0.46 5
0.0 0.55 5

0.08 0.0 -6
0.08 0.08 7
0.08 0.14 -8
0.08 0.33 9
0.08 0.46 -10
0.08 0.55 -10

0.14 0.0 11
0.14 0.08 -12
0.14 0.14 13
0.14 0.33 NaN
0.14 0.46 15
0.14 0.55 15

0.33 0.0 -16
0.33 0.08 17
0.33 0.14 -18
0.33 0.33 19
0.33 0.46 -20
0.33 0.55 -20

0.46 0.0 21
0.46 0.08 -22
0.46 0.14 23
0.46 0.33 -24
0.46 0.46 25
0.46 0.55 25

0.55 0.0 21
0.55 0.08 -22
0.55 0.14 23
0.55 0.33 -24
0.55 0.46 25
0.55 0.55 25
```

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039394/7295599

Comment: pm3d mode is assigning colors to a surface, but there is a hole in your surface due to the NAN coordinate.  Until you fix the hole somehow, perhaps by interpolating from the surrounding points, there will not be a complete surface for it to color.

Comment: I thank you both for your comments. Your link helped me a lot, please see the answer below. I have a question to the "using" part in your script, though, @theozh. Even with the gnuplot documentation it does not become clear what is happening there. Apparently a function that takes two variables/dimensions is required, although it is never needed (I refer to ndx, pdx etc.). Can you elaborate more about the using line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @theozh I figured out a solution to this problem.
I adopted the script by @theozh under [Plotting Heatmap with different column/line widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035321/plotting-heatmap-with-different-column-line-widths/56039394#56039394) to the form below. This yields for the file

```
1 -6 11 -16 21
-2 7 -12 17 -22
3 -8 13 -18 23
-4 9 NaN 19 -24
5 -10 15 -20 25
```

this [plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl8iz.png)
This is the best solution, because the data has this format anyway and the coordinates are a different file that I read in.
Plotscript:

```
CoordsX = "0.04 0.11 0.24 0.40 0.51"
CoordsY = "0.04 0.11 0.24 0.40 0.51"
dimX = words(CoordsX)
dimY = words(CoordsY)
dx(i) = (word(CoordsX,i)-word(CoordsX,i-1))*0.5
dy(i) = (word(CoordsY,i)-word(CoordsY,i-1))*0.5
ndx(i,j) = word(CoordsX,i) - (i-1<1        ? dx(i+1) : dx(i))
pdx(i,j) = word(CoordsX,i) + (i+1>ColCount ? dx(i)   : dx(i+1))
ndy(i,j) = word(CoordsY,j) - (j-1<1        ? dy(j+1) : dy(j))
pdy(i,j) = word(CoordsY,j) + (j+1>RowCount ? dy(j)   : dy(j+1))

set xrange[ndx(1,1):pdx(ColCount,1)]
set yrange[ndy(1,1):pdy(1,RowCount)]
set tic out
max = 25
set cbrange [-max:max]
set palette defined (-max "blue", 0 "white", max "red")

set term png
set output "test.png"
plot for [i=1:dim_x] file u (real(word(CoordsX,i))):1:(ndx(i,int($0))):(pdx(i,int($0))):(ndy(i,int($0+1))):(pdy(i,int($0+1))):i with boxxyerror fs solid 1.0 palette notitle
set output
### end of code
```