# Gnuplot: colors in multiplot not transparent

Tags: colors, gnuplot, transparent, palette

I would like to plot the positive and negative values of a non-equidistant matrix with different palettes (each a logscale), such that the overall *effective* color code is (-max "blue", <1e-6 "white", max "red"). In order to do that it is required to use multiplot for each plot and overlay them perfectly. The problem is now, that the complement values, which should be "NaNs", are plotted as white and not transparent (please see [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92HCl.png)). As a result, the latter plot completely overlays the former, which cannot be seen. I tried to define my own color palette with transparent colors, but cannot make it work with the "plot for" command. (Remark: This is a follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824904/gnuplot-pm3d-nan-value-removes-all-surrounding-rectangles/61892482#61892482).)

Current plotscript:

```
CoordsX = "0.04 0.11 0.24 0.4 0.51"
CoordsY = "0.04 0.11 0.24 0.4 0.51"
dim_x = words(CoordsX)
dim_y = words(CoordsY)

dx(i) = (word(CoordsX,i)-word(CoordsX,i-1))*0.5
dy(i) = (word(CoordsY,i)-word(CoordsY,i-1))*0.5
ndx(i,j) = word(CoordsX,i) - (i-1<1     ? dx(i+1) : dx(i))
pdx(i,j) = word(CoordsX,i) + (i+1>dim_x ? dx(i)   : dx(i+1))
ndy(i,j) = word(CoordsY,j) - (j-1<1     ? dy(j+1) : dy(j))
pdy(i,j) = word(CoordsY,j) + (j+1>dim_y ? dy(j)   : dy(j+1))

set size square
set xrange[ndx(1,1):pdx(dim_x,1)]
set yrange[ndy(1,1):pdy(1,dim_y)] reverse
set tic out

set term png truecolor
set output "test.png"

set multiplot
max = 25
set cbrange [0:max]
set object rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb "grey" fillstyle solid noborder # Only added to see transparency

set palette defined (0 "white", max "blue")
plot for [i=1:dim_x] file u\
(real(word(CoordsX,i))):1:(ndx(i,int($0))):(pdx(i,int($0))):(ndy(i,int($0+1))):(pdy(i,int($0+1))):(column(i)<0?abs(column(i)):NaN)\
with boxxyerror fs transparent solid 1.0 palette notitle
set palette defined (0 "white", max "red")
plot for [i=1:dim_x] file u\
(real(word(CoordsX,i))):1:(ndx(i,int($0))):(pdx(i,int($0))):(ndy(i,int($0+1))):(pdy(i,int($0+1))):(column(i)>0?abs(column(i)):NaN)\
with boxxyerror fs transparent solid 1.0 palette notitle
unset multiplot
set output
```

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1) `multiplot` is not the right mechanism to create a single plot. You will get better results by reorganizing your command sequence into a single `plot` command. If necessary you can split your palette into two halves, a red half and a blue half. E.g.

```
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "dark-red", 1 "white", 2 "dark blue")
set cbrange [0 : 2*max]
plot 'redstuff' using 1:...:(color) fc palette, \
     'bluestuff' using 1:...:(color+max) fc palette
```

2) The fill style you selected is fully opaque.  If you want 50% transparency it needs to be

```
 set style fill transparent solid 0.5
```

3) It is not clear where exactly your NaN values appear. If one of the component rectangles has NaN as a coordinate, it will not be drawn at all - so effectively it is fully transparent.  However providing NaN as a color value will not in general produce transparency.  As a special case the `with image` plot style does know to omit pixels with value NaN, but other plot styles don't have a notion of 'pixels'.

Comment: Thank you, @Ethan, for your comment. Your suggestion 1) seems interesting, however, I do not know how to reconcile it with the "plot for", which is needed for non-equidistant x and y values. 2) is not really what I want. My idea was to have a palette range from (0 "fully transparent", 1 "fully opaque") with red, for example, as the underlying color. To point 3): "with image" has the problem that it does not allow for non-equidistant indices of the matrix. However, this is what I need. Is there a way to tell gnuplot to plot NaN values as transparent?

Comment: (1) No problem: `plot for [i=1:FOO] "redstuff", for [i=1:BAZ] "bluestuff"`. (2) The palette does not have an alpha channel, so you cannot tie transparency to the palette value. (3) No, but you can make the x or y coordinate conditional on the color value: `plot FOO using (column(color)==column(color)? $1 : NaN):2`   The x coordinate will be taken from column 1 except when the color column is NaN.

Comment: Ah ok. What do you mean by "column(color) == column(color)" or is there a typo in your post? So I conclude that it is impossible in gnuplot to have two plots each with a logscale on top of each other!? Because plotting as you suggested would not allow for two different logscales.

Comment: I just meant whatever column the color information is stored in.  You could modify that to be `using 1:2:...:(log(column(color)))` for log scale (not sure what exactly you mean by log scale in this context).

Comment: Ah, ok. I intended to plot it via `set logscale cb` though to have all ranges in one color plot. (The values range from +- 1e-15 to 1e1 and hence the idea of separated positive and negative plots each with a cb logscale. Is there any way to achieve this?